# Iteration in UITableView for a particular cell

Tags: ios

I have data and image in cells of UITableView. I want to change image of a particular cell,
I have a code with each cell.

I am not able to find the way to iterate the tableview for cell.

here is snap shot of my tableview function.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellText = nil;

    NSArray *keys = [[[self packageItems] allKeys] 
                     sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    cellText = [keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];
    //cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

There is another function where i want to change cell image to cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"];

```
- (void)OnAction
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wont to change something in table view with you function you dont have to make new cell, just modify actual cell. Just make condition in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate:

```
if(indexPath == indexToModify) {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"];
} else {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];
}
```

and in your - (void)OnAction method use in the end:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks dear, my problem is to find indexToModify. I will get the key in my OnAction function and this key i have to compare with each cell key, whosoever matches that only i want to change image. Your answer is also helpful to me.